# Finding the answer to an equation in matrix form which relates to each input individually

Tags: matlab

I am trying to recreate the following equation in MATLAB

[image]

This equation calculates the equivalent inertia.

I have values for Ln, Ln-1 and In which are stored in a matrices and I am assuming that Ltotal is simply the Max value of Ln. Den is a matrix storing the values for the equation.

```
% Ln
for lp = 1: bars-1
   ln_p(1,lp) = radius_pin(1) - radius_pin(lp+1);
   ln_w(1,lp) = radius_wheel(1) - radius_wheel(lp+1);
end

% Ln-1
for lp = 1:bars-1
   lnMinus_p(1,lp) = radius_pin(1) - radius_pin(lp);
   lnMinus_w(1,lp) = radius_wheel(1) - radius_wheel(lp);
 end 

% L^3 - (Ln-1)^3
lCubed_p = ln_p.^3 - lnMinus_p.^3;
lCubed_w = ln_w.^3 - lnMinus_w.^3;

% In
  In_p = aChor_p.^3/12;
  In_w = aChor_w.^3/12;

% Denominator of IE equation (inertia)
den_p = lCubed_p./In_p;
den_w = lCubed_w./In_w;
```

I need a code which will find the Ieq values (they should be in a matrix the same size as the inputs)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array `L` which contains all `L_n` values, and similarly for a vector `I` with  values `I_n`, then your equation can be implemented simply:

```
I_eq = L_total^3 / sum( diff(L.^3)./I(2:end) )
```

I'll also re-write your code, because you seem to be missing the point about MATLAB syntax -- it can be pretty close to mathematical notation. I'll leave out the subscripts (because it's the same calculation for both the pin and wheel anyway):

```
lCubed = (radius(1)-radius(2:end)).^3 - (radius(1)-radius(1:end-1)).^3;
In     = 1/12 * aChor_p.^3; 
den    = sum(lCubed./In);
```

Comment: What does the diff(L.^3) do?